# Where can I find more GWT webappcreator templates?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I am learning GWT and to create a new project I call webappcreator with

```
-templates sample,ant,eclipse,readme
```

Using template sample is a great start, but the "sample" is very limited.

Where can I find more templates like "sample"?

I guess I am looking for a simple GWT code generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As found in the gwtproject/gwt source code:
https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/tree/c9c32256f6ffb8ca69f50693a06b91bc25331fef/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/tools/templates

- ant
- eclipse
- maven
- readme
- sample

Comment: That's it? Not even Gradle? Oh my…